# Selection Values reduced based on another selection option in odoo 11?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I have a Custom selection field salary band,The fields contains many values.

```
'0-4K', '4K-12K', '12K-16K', '16K-18K', '>18K',**strong text** 'Above 4000', 'Below 4000',
'No Salary',
```

These are the values used in salary band.

My question is 
I have another selection when I choose a particular option the salary band field must reduce to the **'ABOVE 4000', 'BELOW 4000', 'NO SALARY'** the 3 options.

how can i implement this?

I ***use domain but noting work***, is this possible in odoo?

Answer (score 2):

In short changing the value of `selection` field in Odoo dynamically in the `view` is not possible, If you really need this behavior
You need to use `many2one`. You can create a model for `salary band` to hold this values and use `domain` in your view to limit the searching result.